# Can you depopulate a populated child array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have populated a child array:

```
Model.populate(cars, 'partIds', function(err, cars) { ...
```

I do that as I need look at part objects.  However there are cases where I don't want to return that populated array.

Checking docs you an depopulate in the toObject options.  However I don't have the info I need when toObject is called to determine if I would like to depopulate.

Even worse it looks like I would have to loop all cars returned and call toObject on each car object.

Is there way to depopulate the array:

```
Model.depopulate(cars, 'partIds, function(err, cars) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally just do what Reto suggests but you could also depopulate directly from the document too. Something like this:

```
cars.forEach(function (car) { car.depopulate('partIds'); });
```

see: [Mongoose#Document.depopulate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-depopulate)

Answer (score 0):

We just set the property to the _id of the populated object in this case.

```
car.part = car.part._id
```

Never did it with an array of populated objects, but I think you could just iterate through the array.

Comment: Sure, but then calls to doc.populated() do not return the correct result.  Which I need in my transform (toJSON) function.

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer is late to the party but this should help:

```
const objectifiedCar = car.toObject();
delete objectifiedCar["part_name"];
```